# Kafka - run from application server (wildfly)

Tags: apache-kafka, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to run a kafka consumer within an application server (wildfly swarm). 
Whenever I start the consumer there I get:

```
KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/group/owners/testtopic/0
```

I can start the consumer via the main(String[] args) method.

The ACL's are configured as well:

```
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testtopic

call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --add --allow-principal User:anonymous --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181  --allow-host http://localhost:8082 --operation Read --operation Write --topic testtopic
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181  --allow-host 127.0.0.1 --operation Read --operation Write --topic testtopic
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --add --allow-principal User:bob --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181  --allow-host http://localhost:8082 --operation Read --operation Write --topic testtopic
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181  --allow-host http://localhost:8082 --operation Read --operation Write --topic testtopic

call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:anonymous --consumer --topic testtopic --group group --allow-host http://localhost:8082
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --consumer --topic testtopic --group group --allow-host 127.0.0.1
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:bob --consumer --topic testtopic --group group --allow-host http://localhost:8082
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --consumer --topic testtopic --group group --allow-host http://localhost:8082

call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:anonymous --producer --topic testtopic --allow-host http://localhost:8082
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --producer --topic testtopic --allow-host 127.0.0.1
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:bob --producer --topic testtopic --allow-host http://localhost:8082
call kafka\bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --producer --topic testtopic --allow-host http://localhost:8082
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?